# How to create a patient table from an existing role table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So i am lost and i hope someone can help me.

I have a User model that has a name and email fields.
A Role User model that has a many to many relationship where a user_id has a role_id
A Role model that has the role name.

My question is how can i create a new patient table where the role is patient from the existing tables?

any help would be much APPRECIATED!

Comment: how does your role model look likes? did you have a role permissions table? if you checking a role by only the role name just create a patient role then assign it to that user model you want, if there is have permissions table you have to make permission as well,

Comment: in my roles table i have id with string name. And in my role_user table i have the user_id that references the user and role_id that references the role. So in my roles table i have id 1 Admin, id 2 Dentist and id 3 patient. i can provide more details if you need i really need help

Comment: grate, then you are having many too many relationships, where are you facing the problem? I hope this video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZOgH3-0Bko&t=250s

Answer (score 0):

You could just bin this too and use https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

This is all done for you. Create a permission or role give the user the role and all is done for you. Just use the associations set up in the package.  Way more powerful than creating from scratch. All the heavy lifting is done and much more powerful for your application.